# Caption of a tikz figure

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to adjust the position of rectangle in the caption of a tikz figure.
It should be go down slightly. Also in caption, it is coming "Fig.X 1-". I want to remove
extra "1 -". How to do these? This is my code

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[labelsep=endash]{caption}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig X.}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.18]
\foreach \x in {1,...,50}
\fill[red] (1.1*\x,3) rectangle (1.1*\x+1,0);
\foreach \x in {1,5,7,10,16,22}
\fill[blue] (1.1*\x,3) rectangle (1.1*\x+1,0);
\foreach \x in {2,14,35,44,46}
\fill[green] (1.1*\x,3) rectangle (1.1*\x+1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{ \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.18] \fill[gray!=10] (0, 3 ) rectangle (0.75, 0 ); \end{tikzpicture}: X }

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I assume you are using standalone while debugging, since the figure counter in only meaningful in the main document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

Before `tikzpicture` in caption you should insert command `\protect`:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage[labelsep=endash]{caption}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig X.}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.18]
\foreach \x in {1,...,50}
\fill[red] (1.1*\x,3) rectangle (1.1*\x+1,0);
\foreach \x in {1,5,7,10,16,22}
\fill[blue] (1.1*\x,3) rectangle (1.1*\x+1,0);
\foreach \x in {2,14,35,44,46}
\fill[green] (1.1*\x,3) rectangle (1.1*\x+1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{\protect\tikz{\fill[gray!30] (0,0) rectangle (0.15,2ex);}: X }
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Off-topic:**
I would draw your image without scaling, with white borders of rectangles and with relative coordinates for their sizes:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[labelsep=endash]{caption}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig X.}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {1,...,50}
    \draw[white,fill=red] (0.2*\x,0)   rectangle ++(0.2,0.6);
\foreach \x in {1,5,7,10,16,22}
    \draw[white,fill=blue] (0.2*\x,0)  rectangle ++(0.2,0.6);
\foreach \x in {2,14,35,44,46}
    \draw[white,fill=green] (0.2*\x,0) rectangle ++(0.2,0.6);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{\protect\tikz{\fill[gray!30] (0,0) rectangle (0.15,2ex);}: X }
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The compilation result is similar as before:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. How to remove "1 -" from the caption?

Comment: That means, that `X` is actually figure number? This problem is not mentioned in your question ... and probably deserve new question. Try `\caption*{Fig X. -- \protect\tikz{\fill[gray!30] (0,0) rectangle (0.15,2ex);}: X }
`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes it is working.

Comment: Or `\renewcommand\thefigure{X}` or possibly `\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\Roman{figure}}` for figure 10.